# Is there a way to access the --ours or --theirs revision using the show command

Tags: git

So I am in the middle of a merge conflict between two binary files that I would like to examine their contents.

I understand that the current branch has the ours revision and I can use that to retrieve the content of the file using the show command.

My question is about what revision do I use to retrieve the theirs binary contents of the file using show. I know I can check it out then read the contents, but I want to know if I can skip the checking out step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltngtltpathgtemegem0READMEememREADMEem

```
git show :0:file
git show :1:file
git show :2:file
git show :3:file
```

Comment: How does this scale with an N way octopus merge? I'm assuming it starts from 2 up to N+2?

Comment: No, there are only 3 stages. 0 means "merge is not in progress". From the docs linked above: «During a merge, stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch’s version (typically the current branch), and stage 3 is the version from the branch which is being merged.» I don't know what to do if there are many branches being merged.

Comment: After trying to test an octopus merge and reading around, it seems that it doesn't do what I was expecting. It does not create indexes beyond the ones specified in the docs. Octopus merges are intended for simple cases that don't deal with conflicts in the same file in multiple branches.